# why can the Sender field not be easily configured?

Tags: email, smtp, spam, rfc, smtp-headers

To clarify [this](https://serverfault.com/a/824887/132080) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/218643/correct-use-of-smtp-sender-header) explanation for `Sender:`:

> In brief, From: in the message indicates the mailbox of whoever wrote
>   the message, Sender: indicates the entity which sent a message on
>   behalf of someone else, and To: and Cc: indicate the intended
>   recipient mailbox. The RFCs define other header fields you may be
>   interested in, as well.

I notice that `alpine` inserts the senders FQDN as `<user>@<domain>` in the `Sender:` field.  While the `From:` field can be modified in `alpine` by modifying the `Customized-Headers` setting, attempts to set the `Sender:` field fail.

This looks to be an anti-spam technique?  How does, or does it, relate to Sender Policy Framework?

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_authentication

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Related_Requests_For_Comments

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#Strict_enforcement_of_RFC_standards

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of technics used to avoid sender forging:

- Users except root can't assign arbitrary `SENDER` header, MTA
  override it anyway by actual username@domain.
- Submission from non-local domains to nonlocal domains is completely denied on the MTA.
- He who want to send the message from non-local domain to the non-local domain should be authorized on MTA first.
- MTA for recipient-domain checks whether the sending MTA belongs to the list of authorized sender's domain submitters (SPF)
- DomainKey pair verified - submitter's public one from DNS must match with the private one (DKIM)
- DMARC = SPF + DKIM

Answer (score 0):

From `M S C` the help file in `alpine`:

> ```
>                                       FEATURE: Scramble the Message-ID When Sending
> ```
>
> Normally the Message-ID header that Alpine generates when sending a
>   message contains the name of the computer from which the message is
>   being sent. Some believe that this hostname could be used by spammers
>   or could be used by others for nefarious purposes. If this feature is
>   set, that name will be transformed with a simple Rot13 transformation.
>   The result will still have the correct syntax for a Message-ID but the
>   part of the MessageID that is often a domain name will not be an
>   actual domain name because the letters will be scrambled.
>
> It is possible (but unlikely?) that some spam detection software will
>   use that as a reason to reject the mail as spam. It has also been
>   reported that some spam detection software uses the fact that there
>   are no dots after the "@" as a reason to reject messages. If your
>   PC-Alpine Message-ID is using a name without a dot that is because
>   that is what Windows thinks is your "Full computer name". The method
>   used to set this varies from one type of Windows to another but check
>   under Settings -> Control Panel
>   -> System and look for Network Identification or Computer Name or something similar. How to set it is beyond the scope of Alpine.

which ***seems*** to both scramble the `message-id` field and, apparently, obviates the need for a `sender` field (at least from `alpine`).  In this way, the `sender` field is side-stepped.